# What is this object in Altium Designer?

Tags: schematics, altium

[image]

I haven't used a newer version and this object looks new to me.

Comment: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-signal-harness?version=21

Comment: Your edit has removed the figure, what renders your question meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [signal harness](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/schematic-signal-harness?version=21) for signals